# Why doesn't TeX have hkern and vkern?

Tags: tex-core

We have `\hskip`, `\vskip`, and `\mskip`, but only `\kern` and `\mkern`. Why doesn't TeX distinguish between horizontal and vertical kerns like it does for skips?

Comment: Not a proper answer, but kerning is, by definition, horizontal, unless you consider vertical typesetting.

Comment: `\kern` inserts a horizontal kern when TeX is in "horizontal mode" -- and a vertical kern when TeX is in "vertical mode". No need for two separate commands. See p. 280 of the TeXbook.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio not in tex: you kan kern between paragraphs rather than use vskip, if you wish.

Comment: @Mico Sorry for the late reply. I realize `\hkern` and `\vkern` aren't necessary given the current semantics of `\kern`, but that still doesn't explain the lack of symmetry. `\hkern` and `\vkern` could have been added with the same mode changing semantics as `\hskip` and `\vskip`. Alternatively, like wipet mentions, there could have just been a single `\insertskip` primitive that works like `\kern` but with glue. Thus, I think egreg has provided the best answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no annotation in `errorlog.tex` about the introduction of `\kern`, but a note of 1978-03-27 says

```
S227. Represent italic corrections as boxes, not glue, so that they won't be broken.
        [The |\kern| command doesn't exist yet.] @1113
```

So this is possibly where the idea of `\kern` started to arise and it also can explain why there is no distinction between vertical and horizontal kerns: they have the same properties of boxes (so they behave differently in horizontal and vertical mode) plus the ability to disappear at line/page breaks.

While users want to know or to specify what kind of glue (skip) is appended to what list, programmers should know why they're adding a kern and it makes little sense to say `\vkern` at some point: vertical kerns are things to be added as final touches. On the other hand, saying `\vskip 1pc` (or whatever) means “leave a vertical space” and must end a paragraph.

Note also that two primitives instead of one would increase the size of the program and there's at least another example of a primitive with a dual function, namely `\span`.

And as far as implementation is concerned, `\kern` appends a kern item to the current list, so it's not important to know *what* kind of list it's being built.

Answer (score 15):

`\kern` inserts the kern in any mode: in vertical mode, it is vertical kern, in horizontal or math mode it is horizontal kern. This is most simple implementation.

On the other hand, `\vskip` inserts its glue only in vertical mode. If it is used in horizontal mode then `\vskip` emits the `\par` token to the input queue and waits to the processing given by this `\par`. This is the principle of "to be read again" used in TeX at most other cases. We can except that: after the `\par` is processed, TeX gets to vertical mode, so `\vskip` insets the glue now.

You can see that this is somewhat more complicated implementation than `\kern`.

`\hskip` works similarly: it inserts glue if it is in horizontal or math mode and it starts the paragraph if it is in vertical mode.

You can implement `\hkern` and `\vkern` by:

```
\def\hkern{\leavevmode\kern}
\def\vkern{\par\kern}
```

More interesting question would be: why there is no universal `\insertskip` which inserts vertical or horizontal skip depending on the TeX mode (like `\kern`). But this is the question addressed only to the author of TeX. Of course, you can define:

```
\def\insertskip{\relax\ifvmode\vskip\else\hskip\fi}
```